# android - set content view

Tags: android, view

I have a class extends View named GameView. In MainActivity I put it as contentView:

```
    if(Const.gameView == null){
        Const.gameView = new GameView(this);
        Const.gameView.setViews(Const.chickenArr,Const.chickenViewArr,message,score_message , this.importantMessage  , this.showTimerMessage);
        setContentView(Const.gameView);

    }
```

Here I face a problem. When I goes out the activty and then return back , I want to show again my GameView.

When I use the code above , when I came back again to the MainActivity , I didn't see my gameView.
When I change the code by setting the setContentView(Const.gameView); outside the "if" I get an error

```
11-10 22:17:35.821: E/AndroidRuntime(1580): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

What should I do?

GameView:

```
public GameView(Context context) {
    super(context);     
    int picture = Const.a1;
    if(backgroundBitmap == null)
        backgroundBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), picture);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public void setViews(Chicken[] chickenArr, ChickenView[] chickenViewArr,Messages message , Messages messageScore,
        Messages gameoverMes , Messages showRemailTimeMes) {
    this.chickenArr = chickenArr;
    this.chickenViewArr = chickenViewArr;

    this.message=message;
    this.  messageScore =   messageScore;
    this.gameoverMes =gameoverMes;
    this.showRemailTimeMes=showRemailTimeMes;
}

   @Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    canvas.drawBitmap(this.backgroundBitmap, 1, 1, null);

    //meassage
    this.message.onDraw(canvas);
        ......
```

}

Comment: can you post your GameView here

Comment: are Chicken and ChikenView instance of View?

Comment: ChikenView is a class extends View and has a filed whose type is Chicken (regular class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this...

```
if(Const.gameView == null){
    Const.gameView = new GameView(this);
    Const.gameView.setViews(Const.chickenArr,Const.chickenViewArr,message,score_message , this.importantMessage  , this.showTimerMessage);
    setContentView(Const.gameView);
} else {
    ViewParent parent = Const.gameView.getParent();
    if(parent != null && parent instanceof ViewGroup) {
       ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup)parent;
       viewGroup.removeView(Const.gameView);
    }
  setContentView(Const.gameView);
}
```

and I observed that you are maintaining static references to Views in Const class. I suggest you that don't maintain static reference for Views as Context is associated with every View and thus leads to leakage of Context...

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in oncreate if you have this peice of code in onresume

Comment: it's not an answer. it should be comment

Comment: this is in onCreate. In the first time I insert to MainActivty I do see the gameView. Only in the second time the problem appear

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the same view in multiple activities. Instead you should create a new instance of the view

```
 like every time you have to create new instance
Const.gameView = new GameView(this);
```

Comment: I try now to delete the "if part" from the onCreate(the code in my question" and instead I wrote in onResume the lines :  Const.gameView = new GameView(this);
  Const.gameView.setViews(Const.chickenArr,Const.chickenViewArr,message,score_message , this.importantMessage  , this.showTimerMessage);
  setContentView(Const.gameView);

And I get the same error (the log one..) as in my question